# Make two lines from points

Tags: postgis

How can I make two lines from points, considering time intervals, i.e. from 04:00:00 to 12:00:00 and 12:00:01 to 23:59:59?

```
"POINT(-46.583483 -23.463208)";"04:49:10"
"POINT(-46.583483 -23.463208)";"04:49:13"
"POINT(-46.57166 -23.50644)";"14:58:28"
"POINT(-46.57166 -23.50644)";"14:58:31"
"POINT(-46.579627 -23.450293)";"04:39:56"
"POINT(-46.579627 -23.450293)";"04:39:54"
"POINT(-46.567625 -23.517135)";"05:18:44"
"POINT(-46.567625 -23.517135)";"05:18:41"
"POINT(-46.582715 -23.461313)";"15:41:42"
"POINT(-46.582715 -23.461313)";"15:41:45"
```

Comment: Do you mean ordered by the 2nd column by time and split into two groups before and after 12:00

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

//TABLE

```sql
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for teste_p
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "teste_p";
CREATE TABLE "teste_p" (
"id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('teste_p_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"geom" "public"."geometry",
"time_2" time(6)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)

;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of teste_p
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('1', '0101000020E6100000D0622992AF4A47C0DE3EABCC947637C0', '04:49:10');
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('2', '0101000020E6100000D0622992AF4A47C0DE3EABCC947637C0', '04:49:13');
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('3', '0101000020E61000003737A6272C4947C0E162450DA68137C0', '14:58:28');
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('4', '0101000020E61000003737A6272C4947C0E162450DA68137C0', '14:58:31');
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('5', '0101000020E61000007670B037314A47C0239EEC66467337C0', '04:39:56');
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('6', '0101000020E61000007670B037314A47C0239EEC66467337C0', '04:39:54');
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('7', '0101000020E61000002DB29DEFA74847C0F19D98F5628437C0', '05:18:44');
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('8', '0101000020E61000002DB29DEFA74847C0F19D98F5628437C0', '05:18:41');
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('9', '0101000020E6100000BFF1B567964A47C03B38D89B187637C0', '15:41:42');
INSERT INTO "teste_p" VALUES ('10', '0101000020E6100000BFF1B567964A47C03B38D89B187637C0', '15:41:45');
```

//QUERY

```sql
SELECT
st_makeline(teste_p.geom)
FROM
(SELECT * FROM sema.teste_p ORDER BY sema.teste_p.time_2) teste_p
WHERE
teste_p.time_2 > '04:00:00' AND teste_p.time_2 < '12:00:00'
UNION ALL
(SELECT
st_makeline(teste_p.geom)
FROM
(SELECT * FROM sema.teste_p ORDER BY sema.teste_p.time_2) teste_p
WHERE
teste_p.time_2 > '12:00:00' AND teste_p.time_2 <= '23:59:59')
```

Comment: I think you need to order the points according to time. Otherwise, the polyline creation can be a bit random. Adding "ORDER BY time_2" will do.

Comment: You were right. I redid the query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small standard boiler plate perl script which I often use for fast an dirty data imports (little bit simplified). I assume you have you way points in the file `data` in the same directory.

1. It reads and parses the way points in a dictionary,
2. sorts the way points by the time and
3. splits the track if a cut_off value occours
4. writes the sql code

The Script gives you:

1. The sorted hash

```bash
04:39:54 = -46.579627 -23.450293
04:39:56 = -46.579627 -23.450293
04:49:10 = -46.583483 -23.463208
04:49:13 = -46.583483 -23.463208
05:18:41 = -46.567625 -23.517135
05:18:44 = -46.567625 -23.517135
14:58:28 = -46.57166 -23.50644
14:58:31 = -46.57166 -23.50644
15:41:42 = -46.582715 -23.461313
15:41:45 = -46.582715 -23.461313
```

2. The time sorted lines

```bash
04:39:54-05:18:44 = -46.579627 -23.450293,-46.579627 -23.450293,-46.583483 -23.463208,-46.583483 -23.463208,-46.567625 -23.517135,-46.567625 -23.517135
14:58:28-15:41:45 = -46.57166 -23.50644,-46.57166 -23.50644,-46.582715 -23.461313,-46.582715 -23.461313
```

3. The SQL conform output (straight forward, not tested)

```sql
CREATE TABLE wp (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, tm_from TIME, tm_to TIME);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','wp','geom',4326,'LINESTING',2);
INSERT INTO wp (id, tm_from, tm_to, geom) VALUES
(1, '04:39:54', '05:18:44', 
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTING(-46.579627 -23.450293,-46.579627 -23.450293,-46.583483 -23.463208,-46.583483 -23.463208,-46.567625 -23.517135,-46.567625 -23.517135)',EPSG)),
(2, '14:58:28', '15:41:45', 
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTING(-46.57166 -23.50644,-46.57166 -23.50644,-46.582715 -23.461313,-46.582715 -23.461313)',EPSG));
```

Here is the code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# ---------------------------------
# Collect way points into a line
# ---------------------------------
# Settings
# ----------------------------------
use strict;
use constant TEST_LINE => '"POINT(-46.583483 -23.463208)";"04:49:10"';
use constant FILE      => './data'; # File with way points
use constant DEBUG     => 0;        # Show debung messages
use constant CUT_OFF   => 3600;     # CUT_OFF Value in seconds for a point group
use constant EPSG      => 4326;     # The spatial reference ID

# ----------------------------------
# 1. Read the file into a hash with the
# times as key (hopfully no duplicates
# timestamps here)
# ----------------------------------
my %points; # Dictionary for the time keyed points

# Open the data file
open(FH, '<', FILE) || die "Cannot open FILE!\n";
# Iterate through the lines
while (my $line = <FH>) {

  next if $line =~ /^$/;     # Skip empty lines
  next if $line =~ /^\s+$/;  # Skip lines with whitespace

  # parse the point an time for each line
  my ($pt, $tm) = &parsePoint($line);

  # store it in the dictionary
  $points{$tm} = $pt;
}
close(FH);

print "\n1. The sorted hash\n";
&listSortHash(\%points);

# ----------------------------------
# 2. Group the data
# ----------------------------------
my $keyFirst  = ''; # The time key of the first wp in the group
my $keyLast   = ''; # The time key of the last wp in the group
my $tmLast    = -1; # The time of the wp before
my $tmCurrent = -1; # The time of the current wp
my %lines;          # Dictionary where collect our points;
my @coords = ();    # Coordinate entry for the linestring

# Iterate over the way points
for my $time (sort keys %points) {

    # Get the point for the time
    my $point = $points{$time};

    # get the time params and calc the second
    my ($hr, $min, $sec) = split(/:/, $time);
    $tmCurrent = $hr *3600 + $min * 60 + $sec;

    # Init the time marks for the first wp
    if ( $tmLast == -1 ) {
       $keyFirst = $time;
       $keyLast  = $time;
       $tmLast   = $tmCurrent;
    }

    # The time gap
    my $deltaTime = $tmCurrent - $tmLast;
    print "DT: $deltaTime TC $tmCurrent TL $tmLast  \n"
      if DEBUG;

    # If the gap between two way points is to large
    if ( $deltaTime > CUT_OFF) {

      # Build the from to key as $keyFirst.'-'.$keyLast;
      # Store the data in the dictionary as a
      # comma seperated string
      $lines{$keyFirst.'-'.$keyLast} = join(',', @coords);

      # Clear the coordinate stack
      @coords = ($point);

      # set the frist time key to current
      $keyFirst =  $time;
      # Clear the prevoiuse time marks
      # ..we have a new line string
      $keyLast = ''; $tmLast = $tmCurrent;
    }
    # If we are in the time track
    else {
      # store the data at the point stack
      push( @coords, $point);

      # and update the prevoiuse time marks
      $keyLast = $time; $tmLast = $tmCurrent;
    }
}
# Flush the last line
$lines{$keyFirst.'-'.$keyLast} = join(',', @coords) if $#coords>0;

# Print out the stuff
print "\n2. The time sorted lines\n";
&listSortHash(\%lines);


# ----------------------------------
# 3. Print it as a set of POSTGIS
# conform linestrings
# ----------------------------------
my $cnt = 0;
print "\n3. The SQL conform output\n\n";

# Create table statement
print "CREATE TABLE wp (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, tm_from TIME, tm_to TIME);\n";

# Create the geometry column
print "SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','wp','geom',4326,'LINESTRING',2);\n";

# An the data dump
print "INSERT INTO wp (id, tm_from, tm_to, geom) VALUES\n";
for my $time (sort keys %lines) {
  $cnt++;
  my $coord = $lines{$time};
  my ($from, $to) = split(/\-/,$time);
  print ",\n" if $cnt > 1;
  print "($cnt, '$from', '$to', \nST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING($coord)',EPSG))";
}
print";\n";

# ----------------------------------
# Parsing something like that
# "POINT(-46.583483 -23.463208)";"04:49:10"
# &parsePoint(TEST_LINE);
# ----------------------------------
sub parsePoint($) {
  my $line = shift;
  # remove linefeed
  chomp($line);
  print "PP 1: ", $line, "\n" if DEBUG;

  # remove " POINT ( )
  $line =~ s/\"//g;
  $line =~ s/POINT//g;
  $line =~ s/\(//g;
  $line =~ s/\)//g;
  print "PP 2: ", $line, "\n" if DEBUG;

  # split points an time
  my ($point, $time) = split(/;/, $line);
  print "pp 3: point:", $point,  "\n" if DEBUG;
  print "pp 4: time: ", $time,   "\n" if DEBUG;

  # return the result
  return ($point, $time);
}

# ---------------------------------
# List the hash prints you hash
# ---------------------------------
sub listSortHash($) {
  my %dict = %{$_[0]};
  for my $key (sort keys %dict) {
    my $value = $dict{$key};
    print $key," = ", $value, "\n";
  }
}

# ----------------------------------
# EOF
# ----------------------------------
```